# Problems with dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 3

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kernel, uefi, acer

I recently bought a Acer Aspire A315-41 and tried to implement dual-boot for work reasons. But am having a lot of problems. I have an SSD of 119.2 GB, where Windows is installed, and a 931.5 GB HDD, where Ubuntu is located. The installation worked just fine, the GNU GRUB screen is appearing when turning on the computer normally. But when I boot Ubuntu, a black screen appears that reads:

```
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

And then boots normally. However, I realized that Ubuntu is VERY unstable. The screen is flashing and freezing constantly. I do not know what to do! I tryed to install Ubuntu several times and also formatted my HDD. But this message is ALWAYS there. Could this be a version 18 problem? I have not tried to install another version of Ubuntu.

I have already run the command:

```
sudo apt update && updrade
```

It is important to say that my UEFI is `Insyde V1.06` and my `Kernel` is `5.3.0-46-generic x86_64`. I also find very strange that the line of code above is from integrity, since my boot manager is UEFI, not BIOS (I dont even have the option to change UEFI mode). On my HDD, besides Linux Ubuntu partition, I have an EFI System partition, witch is correctly reconized by Ubuntu (I discover this information by typing the command `sudo cat /etc/fstab` on my terminal). Oh, and my Secure Boot is disabled.

I also read that my machine have a rudimentary UEFI, to say the least...

If anyone can help me, I will be forever grateful. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is certainly stable. The problem lies with Acer machines which require their own special UEFI configuration as far as an Ubuntu/Windows dual boot is concerned. I would have a look at [this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot) for a more comprehensive approach if the first suggestion doesn't fix things.

Comment: @Carolina You commented that Paul's comment was really helpful, yet this page remains unresolved.  Will you be able to post an answer yourself?  Should Paul post an answer?